# VBA number formatting

Tags: excel, vba, accounting

I am writing a macro package to format numbers in accounting format so that I don't have to click "alt - h - fm" every time I want to make a number accounting format (which my job requires).  I have the code up to a certain point, but it is not matching excel's accounting format.  Right now the $ appears one space before the number, rather than at the left edge of the cell (like it does for excel's accounting format).  My present code formats to thousands with no decimals, all that is wrong is that the dollar sign doesn't appear at the left edge of the cell.

Here is my code for the number format:

```
Selection.NumberFormat = "_(* $ #,##0_);_(* $ (#,##0);_(* ""$  -""?_);_(@_)"
```

How should I change it so that the dollar sign appears at the beginning of the cell?

Thank you for the help! this has been stumping me for a while now...

Answer (score 3):

You need to put the `$` before the `*`: `_($* #,##0_);` etc.

Also, if you want to replicate an existing format, you can always use the macro recorder, change a cell to the format you want, and check the auto-generated code.